# Proxy cannot get method in extended class

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I am trying to use a `Proxy`, and I am having issues. I have a class like so:

```
export class Builder {
    public doSomething(...args: (string | number | Raw | Object)[]): this {
        // Do stuff
        return this
    }
}

export class ModelBase extends Builder {
    protected _items = {}
}

export class Model extends ModelBase {

    public constructor(options?: ModelSettings) {
      super(options)
      return new Proxy(this, {
        get: function (target, property) {
          return target._items[property] || target
        }
      })
    }

    public static create() {
        return new this()
    }

}
```

I then extend `Model` like so:

```
export class MyClass extends Model {

    public constructor() {
        super({/* Some options go here */})
        // Do some stuff
    }

    public static getItems() {
        let t = this.create()
        t.doSomething()
    }

}
```

Then I call `getItems()` which creates an instance of the class.

```
MyClass.getItems()
```

When I run this, I get the error:

> TypeError: t.doSomething is not a function

Where `doSomething()` is within the class `ModelBase`. If I comment out the `Proxy` things work as usual. So, I would like to know why I can't access the parent class.

Comment: `class` is a keyword; I'm not sure if this relates to the problem at all, but I'd definitely not call your variable `class`.

Comment: I am not actually using `class`, it was just an example. I renamed it though.

Comment: does `model` or `modelBase` have an `_items` property? And if so does _items have a `doSomething` method?

Comment: `ModelBase` has both `_items` and `doSomething`

Comment: please include that in your example, because from the error you quoted  it appears to have `_items` but no `_items.doSomething`. So the proxy falls back to returning the target (ie, the entire object), which is not a function.

Comment: I just realized it is above that... But I have updated it to reflect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proxy is trying to find `target._items.doSomething`, but that doesn't exist. `target.doSomething` does exist, but it's not looking for that. As a result, it falls back to returning `target`, which is the object as a whole. The object, is not a function, and thus the error.

As for how to fix this, that depends on what you're trying to achieve with the proxy. If there's a limited set of properties that the proxy should be paying attention to, you could check those explicitly. Or more generally you might be able to check whether `target[property]` exists, then fall back to `target._items[property]` and only then fall back to `target`. Again, it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: When I query the database, `_items` gets filled using key/value where `key` is the db column name and `value` is the value.

Comment: Looks like `return target[property] || target._items[property]` works.